# Bulk cropping white unevenly spaced white borders

Tags: software, photo-editing, technique, cropping

So i have a bulk of images having white border and text embedded at bottom.I tried to use irfanviewer xnviewer to bulk crop it however it didnt work...the problem is the images have same specific resolution is 1024 * 768 however border around it doesnt always start froma specified pixel at top left corner. So batch croppers dont work. Is there a method to detect and remove the white borders while preseving the 1024 *768 size?

Comment: Here's [one cross-platform method](http://snipplr.com/view/52310/automatically-trimremove-whiteblackany-borders-from-images/).

Comment: Is it necessary to crop the images, or would replacing the white border with another colour work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The person/program that added the white borders in the first place, saved the image at a resolution of 1024 by 768. After removing the borders by cropping the  image, the resolution will decrease no matter what. Unless there's a program that can up the res of a picture. Even when the resolution is bumped up, the quality of the photo will stay the same, what are you trying to use this picture for?

Edit: shoot, I didn't understand the question at first, the answer above makes no sense  I'm sorry

To solve the problem you're having, you're going to have to crop them individually or you can put the images in groups that have basically the same frame size and do each group at a time.